# Script to do delete and creation in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm wondering if anyone can recommend any scripting plugins for Eclipse that would allow me to delete a file from one project and add it to another project as well as change any references from the old location to point to the new one.

Comment: Refactoring already does that.

Comment: If the file is a java class then it will be handles when you click and drag the file. If its a different file, you will have to do a search-replace to change location.

Answer (score 0):

Locate the file in **Package Explorer**. Right click on it. Go to `Refactor > Move` then select the destination and **update reference** option. All references will be update automatically. You can also preview changes by clicking on the **Preview** button.